# How can I convert "SignalProducer<Bool, NoError>" to "SignalProducer<Bool, NSError>" of ReactiveCocoa 3?

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-3

I tried creating an instance of `Action<AnyObject?, Bool, NSError>` of ReactiveCocoa 3.

```
let action: Action<AnyObject?, Bool, NSError> = Action { _ in
    if self.flag {
        return self.fooSignalProducer  // SignalProducer<Bool, NoError>
    } else {
        return self.barSignalProducer  // SignalProducer<Bool, NSError>
    }
}
```

This code isn't able to compile with error `'SignalProducer<Bool, NoError>' is not convertible to 'SignalProducer<Bool, NSError>'`.

How can I convert `SignalProducer<Bool, NoError>` to `SignalProducer<Bool, NSError>`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `mapError` operator. Something along the lines of:

```
self.fooSignalProducer |> mapError { _ in NSError() }
```

**Edit:**

As Justin points out below, `promoteErrors` is specifically designed for this case:

```
self.fooSignalProducer |> promoteErrors(NSError)
```

Comment: `promoteErrors()` is useful for the specific case of upgrading from `NoError`.

Comment: @JustinSpahr-Summers Thanks for pointing that out! I've amended the answer.